# Receiving an error in Android Studio while making Weather app. Whats wrong with my code?

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile, weather-api, openweathermap

While making Android App I'm receiving such an error. It would be great if somebody can give me a prompt concerning my code.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your URL is malformed. just add method of your URL.

for example add `http://` in start of your URL. thats make your address like this: `http://api.....`

Comment: thanks but now I have another error "java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to api.openweather.org not permitted" What can I do to solve the problem?

Comment: if your problem is solved just fill the solved question by this answer. you can add ```android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"``` to your manifest ```application``` tag. see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted